# How to make use of ipt trace

Tags: windows, debugging, x86

So I compiled [winipt](https://github.com/ionescu007/winipt) and ptdump from [libipt](https://github.com/intel/libipt) I got a trace but ptdump prints garbage. Additionally I created a dump using `MiniDumpWriteDump` with `MiniDumpWithIptTrace` and opened it both with VS and windbg but I don't think they are recognizing the trace either.

I'm currently downloading intel studio since it has widnbg extensions for ipt support but I've heard also of [REPT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/rept-reverse-debugging-of-failures-in-deployed-software/).

In the video it's showing some futuristic looking windbg and it's setting a hw breakpoint which then triggers on backwards execution.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, but partly you are doing it wrong and Alex's code is not so complete.
Note that Alex's code is a POC as he says, IMHO it's not really complete to go right to a a file and decoder. Also note that ptdump is just an example. If you can find a sample trace that is just pure IPT packets then it will work as is.
Step through how ipttool outputs the data (for one thing it saves a header that you are not accounting for), vs how ptdump loads a binary.

winipt is used in this project:
https://github.com/googleprojectzero/winafl

Unfortunately as we both found there is no official support for Intel PT on Windows yet like there is on Linux which has complete support for it.

Yea apparently they added support to MiniDumpWriteDump(). You can see the support for it by symbols in dbgcore.dll. Could not find any documentation for it either. On MSDN they define the IPT type enums but then there is zero descriptions of what they do.
Parsing a normal/old mini-dump is probably a project in it's self. I bet though if you can parse a normal/default mini-dump, you will figure out how to parse the IPT section out of it too.
Anyhow depending on what you want to do, probably just a a buffer full and it want's to write to a file.

Update:
Actually it looks like PssNtCaptureSnapshot() would give us direct access to a IPT snapshot using the PSS_CAPTURE_IPT_TRACE flag, then followed by a PssQuerySnapshot() function to get the data. Still one will have to parse it considering the headers like struct IPT_TRACE_DATA.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processsnapshot/nf-processsnapshot-psscapturesnapshot